# Group messages into conversations using Mongodb aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have the following collection of messages:

```
{
    "sender_id": 1,
    "sender_name": "Brian",
    "receiver_id": 2,
    "receiver_name": "John",
    "text": "Hey, John, you also have this app!"
},
{
    "sender_id": 2,
    "sender_name": "John",
    "receiver_id": 1,
    "receiver_name": "Brian",
    "text": "Oh yea Brian, wazzup?"
},
{
    "sender_id": 3,
    "sender_name": "Jack",
    "receiver_id": 2,
    "receiver_name": "John",
    "text": "Hey John!"
}
...
```

I want to use MongoDB Aggregation Framework to combine these messages into **dialogs/conversations**. Let's say, I want to fetch all conversations that **John** (id=2) participated in:

```
{
    "other_participant_id": 1,
    "other_participant_name": "Brian",
    "last_message": "Oh yea Brian, wazzup?",
    "count": 2
},
{
    "other_participant_id": 3,
    "other_participant_name": "Jack",
    "last_message": "Hey John!",
    "count": 1
},
```

One way that I found to achieve this is to get the id of the first participant and use `$cond` to determine if `sender_id` or `receiver_id` should be used while grouping:

```
// Let's say we are building this for John, with id=2
db.messages.aggregate(
    [
       {
          $match: { 
            $or: [
                {receiver_id: 2},
                {sender_id: 2}
            ] 
          },
       },
       {
        $sort:{ date: 1 }
       },
       {
          $group:{
            _id: { other_participant_id: { $cond: [{$eq:["$sender_id", 2]}, "$receiver_id", "$sender_id"] } },  
            other_participant_id: { $last: { $cond: [{$eq:["$sender_id", 2]}, "$receiver_id", "$sender_id"] } },
            other_participant_name: { $last: { $cond: [{$eq:["$sender_id", 2]}, "$receiver_name", "$sender_name"] } },      
            last_message: { $last: "$text" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
          }
       }
    ]
);
```

This seems to work, however I find this ugly.
Is there any better or "right" way to achieve this?

Comment: Unless you have another way of identifying the "conversation" ( such as by a "conversationId" ) then the query parameters are essentially the two users for whom you wish to retrieve the data. If your intent here is in fact to *"get the last message in the conversation"* then simply storing such a "conversationId" and a "timestamp" would allow you to very quickly get the "last message". But your question actually does not state clearly what the intent/purpose is. Context matters in order to get the answer you want. You should state what you actually need this for.

Comment: @NeilLunn my intention is to grab the whole conversation and combine it into field "messages", as well as both participants (id and name).

Comment: For what conversation? This is what I am telling you is missing from your question. How would you know what the "conversation" is without supplying the two users who participate? This is what you need to think about. Read the comment and clarify in your question rather than engaging a discussion. Comments are asking you to improve/clarify your question. This is not a chat forum. If you expect an "answer" then you need to make a clear question. Or at least consider what I have basically said that if your data does not present another way to select, then what you have is all you get.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you for your feedback. I updated my question. Please let me know if what I am trying to achieve is still not clear.